# About differentiability of functions.

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Maybe my question is a bad question.

Let $A$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f$ be any function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $f$ be differentiable at $a$ for each $a \in A$.

Then, is there an open set $B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $B \supset A$ and there is a differentiable function $g:B \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(a) = f(a)$ for each $a \in A$ ?

If there is no such $B$ for some $A$ and for some $f$, I am glad.

***My motivation***:
I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.
In this book, there are the following sentences.
I asked the above question after I read the following sentences.

> The definition of $Df(a)$ could be made if $f$ were defined only in
>   some open set containing $a$. Considering only functions defined on
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ streamlines the statement of theorems and produces no
>   real loss of generality. It is convenient to define a function $f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ to be differentiable on $A$ if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ for each $a \in A$. If $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^m$, then $f$ is called differentiable if $f$ can be extended to a differentiable function on some open set containing $A$.

Comment: Can you clarify: Does $A\subset B$ allow $A=B$ or not?

Comment: $A = B$ is allowed. But $B$ must be an open interval. And maybe $A$ is not an open interval. $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the precise definition in your book of "$f$ is differentiable at $a$"?

Answer (score 0):

Not neccessarily. For example, the function $f$, defined as $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&x>0\\0&x\leq 0\end{cases}$$ is differentiable at each $x\in(0,\infty)$, however, its derivative cannot be expanded any further. That is, any function $g$ that is equal to $f$ on $(0,\infty)$ will not be differentiable at $0$.

Comment: There's no suggestion $A$ is an interval.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The question was edited in between, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @5xum I am very sorry. I edited. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Given the notation clarification, this is not enough as we can just take $A=B$ in this case.